# Where are files created using FileOutputStream on Android?

Tags: android, file

I've created a file in my code, as shown below

```
 FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
 osw.write(text);
 osw.flush();
 osw.close();
```

Now, I know that the file is getting created because I can read the file when I do this:

```
     FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("samplefile.txt");
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
     char[] inputBuffer = new char[text.length()];
     isr.read(inputBuffer);
     String readString = new String(inputBuffer);
     System.out.println(readString);
```

So the text is getting read back.
However, I can't find the file on my device. Where does it go?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever tried looking at source code?  The android stuff is easily viewing.  Open the `openFileInput` method and have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the address of it be below line Code

```
 File file = getFileStreamPath("samplefile.txt");
```

And for print it

```
String s  = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 2):

The file is being saved to internal storage (see this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)).

You can retrieve the path of the file with `getFilesDir()` (see this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29)).

The path is /data/data/yourapplicationpackagename/files.

Answer (score 1):

If you googled you could find this site [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)

which mentions

> Android allows to persists application data via the file system. For
>   each application the Android system creates a data/data/[application
>   package] directory.